# jQuery: Issue with nested toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  var target = $($(this).data("target"));
  $(".hidden").not(target).not(this.closest('ul')).removeClass("show");
  target.toggleClass("show");
  $(this).siblings().not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
})
```

```css
* {
  cursor: default;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

li:hover,
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-target=".one">Link One</li>
  <li data-target=".two">Link Two</li>
  <li data-target=".three">Link Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="hidden one">
  Lorem Ipsum One
</div>

<ul class="hidden two">
  <li data-target=".two_one">Link Two One</li>
  <li data-target=".two_two">Link Two Two</li>
</ul>

<div class="hidden two_one">
  Lorem Ipsum Two One
</div>

<div class="hidden two_two">
  Lorem Ipsum Two Two
</div>

<div class="hidden three">
  Lorem Ipsum One
</div>
```

Basically, everything works fine. *But*: If you click **Link Two**, then **Link Two One**, then **Link One**, then **Link Two**, theeeen **Link Two One** is still `active`.

How is it possible to fix that?

Would be very thankful for help! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will help you

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var target = $($this.data("target"));
  $(".hidden").not(target).not(this.closest('ul')).removeClass("show");
  
  $this.siblings().each((i, elm) => {
    var trg = $($(elm).data("target"));
    trg.find("li").removeClass("active");
  });

  $this.each((i, elm) => {
    var trg = $($(elm).data("target"));
    trg.find("li").removeClass("active");
  });
  
  target.toggleClass("show");

  $this.siblings().not(this).removeClass('active');
  $this.toggleClass("active");
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It still doesn't work perfectly. If you click "Link Two", then "Link Two One", then "Link Two" again, and again, then "Link Two One" is still active.

Comment: sorry I got your requirements wrong. I have updated my answer. and here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/t0fwk2bs/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
  var target = $($(this).data("target"));
  $(".hidden").not(target).not(this.closest('ul')).removeClass("show");
  target.toggleClass("show");
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

Comment: – Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work unfortunately.